# Sympy; summing and integrating an indexed variable.

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

The exercise I am trying to recreate is the first one in these [lattice notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0506036). 
[image: question part 1]
[image: question part 2]

I am attempting this in sympy with python3. My attempt is this;

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import a, m
from sympy import IndexedBase, Idx, oo, symbols
# from ipdb import set_trace as st

integrated_path = sympy.Symbol('I')

def V(sym_a, sym_x):
    return (sym_x**2)/sym_a

N, j, j_primed = symbols('N j, j_primed', integer=True)
x = IndexedBase('x')
j_idx = Idx(j)
S = sympy.summation(((m/(2*a)) * (x[j_idx+1] - x[j_idx]**2) + a*V(a, x[j_idx])),
                    (j_idx, 0, N-1))
print("The action ", S)

integrand = sympy.exp(-S)
j_primed_idx = Idx(j_primed, (0, N))
integrated_path = sympy.integrate(integrand, (x[j_primed_idx], -oo, oo))
print("The integrated path is ", integrated_path)

subbed_path = integrated_path.subs({a: 0.5, N: 8, m: 1})
print("The subbed path is ", subbed_path)
```

However, the integration is not recognising `x[j+1]` as being one of `x[j]` therefore it is not integrating over it. The output I'm getting is;

```
The action  Sum(x[j]**2 + m*(x[j + 1] - x[j]**2)/(2*a), (j, 0, N - 1))
The integrated path is  oo*sign(exp(-Sum(x[j]**2, (j, 0, N - 1)) - m*Sum(x[j + 1], (j, 0, N - 1))/(2*a) + m*Sum(x[j]**2, (j, 0, N - 1))/(2*a)))
The subbed path is  oo*sign(exp(-1.0*Sum(x[j + 1], (j, 0, 7))))
```

All of the `x` values should have integrated out, yet one of them remains. So I think I'm using indexed variables incorrectly. Short of hard coding `N` what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy's handling of indexed objects is not nearly sophisticated enough to handle this computation as a human would. In particular, it is not going to understand integration 
 over `(x[j_primed_idx], -oo, oo)` as "integrate over all indexed x". This looks like a single integration to SymPy, and over a variable that's distinct from any `x[j]` because the indices don't look the same. In short, SymPy doesn't really understand how indices work in mathematics.

You'll need to declare the value of `N` upfront to get anything done. And to fix the typo in `(x[j_idx+1] - x[j_idx]**2)` — this should be `(x[j_idx+1] - x[j_idx])**2`. And it's still going to take forever if N is large and `a` and `m` are symbolic. The issue is that there are cases upon cases based on the relative sizes of `a` and `m`. Here is a working version with `N, a, m` all specified upfront — this helps the integrator **a lot**. Note the use of `Rational(1, 2)` instead of a float `0.5` by the way — this matters for SymPy.

```
import sympy
from sympy import oo, symbols
N = 8
a = sympy.Rational(1, 2)
m = 1

def V(sym_a, sym_x):
    return (sym_x**2)/sym_a

x = symbols('x0:{}'.format(N))
S = sympy.Add(*[((m/(2*a)) * (x[j_idx+1] - x[j_idx])**2 + a*V(a, x[j_idx])) for j_idx in range(N-1)])
print("The action ", S)

integrand = sympy.exp(-S)
integrated_path = sympy.integrate(integrand, *[(x[j_primed_idx], -oo, oo) for j_primed_idx in range(N)], conds='none')
print("The integrated and subbed path is ", integrated_path)
```

Output:

```
The action  x0**2 + x1**2 + x2**2 + x3**2 + x4**2 + x5**2 + x6**2 + (-x0 + x1)**2 + (-x1 + x2)**2 + (-x2 + x3)**2 + (-x3 + x4)**2 + (-x4 + x5)**2 + (-x5 + x6)**2 + (-x6 + x7)**2
The integrated and subbed path is  sqrt(377)*pi**4/377
```

And this is how far I can push it with symbolic a and m: N=2 here.

```
import sympy
from sympy import IndexedBase, Idx, oo, symbols
a, m = symbols('a m', positive=True)
N = 2

def V(sym_a, sym_x):
    return (sym_x**2)/sym_a

j, j_primed = symbols('j, j_primed', integer=True)
x = symbols('x0:{}'.format(N))
S = sympy.Add(*[((m/(2*a)) * (x[j_idx+1] - x[j_idx])**2 + a*V(a, x[j_idx])) for j_idx in range(N-1)])
print("The action ", S)

integrand = sympy.exp(-S)
integrated_path = sympy.integrate(integrand, *[(x[j_primed_idx], -oo, oo) for j_primed_idx in range(N)], conds='none')
print("The integrated path is ", integrated_path)

subbed_path = integrated_path.subs({a: sympy.Rational(1, 2), m: 1})
print("The subbed path is ", subbed_path)
```

Output:

```
The action  x0**2 + m*(-x0 + x1)**2/(2*a)
The integrated path is  -I*pi*sqrt(a)*sqrt(4*a**2 + 2*a*m)*Piecewise((I/sqrt(-1 + (4*a**2 + 2*a*m)/(2*a*m)), (4*a**2 + 2*a*m)/(2*a*m) > 1), (1/sqrt(1 - (4*a**2 + 2*a*m)/(2*a*m)), True))/(m*sqrt(a + m/2))
The subbed path is  pi
```